# How to create a Trigger in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

TRIGEER-->To get a column value from one table to other table when i insert values?
I am having two tables(`customer_details` and `loan_balance`).
What i need is, I must get the column (`custid`)of customer_details table to the loan_balance table when i insert the data into the loan_balance table.
 This is the full set up of my query : [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/92021/2)

So i need a trigger to be raised and the data should be updated automatically without dynamic insertion of custid.

Comment: have you read the online doc? have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres has an unconventional way of creating triggers:

1. create a function that returns type `trigger` and return the `NEW` row record
2. create a trigger that executes the function

Here's the code you need:

```
CREATE FUNCTION synch_custid_proc()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.custid = (
        select max(custid)
        from customer_details
        where creditid = NEW.creditid
    );
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER synch_custid_trig
BEFORE INSERT ON loan_amount
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE synch_custid_proc();
```

I chosen to select `max(custid)` rather than simply `custid` when finding the value in case there are multiple rows that match. You might have to adjust this logic to suit your data.

See a [live demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0b95f/1)