# add triggers manually inside my migrations with prisma ORM

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, orm, prisma

I am trying to create triggers using postgresql with *prisma* as ORM
but it seems that it haven't supported triggers yet.
and I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615513/how-to-create-a-trigger-on-a-postgresql-database-managed-by-prisma) ,but i don't want to create my triggers logic in the server level (using middlewares).

now I am asking, can i make my triggers manually inside my database migrations as a migration level, or it may cause some problems?

for example i have the following migrations inside my application

```
├── prisma
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 20230202011931_initial
│   │   │   └── migration.sql
│   │   ├── 20230202012555_default_to_created_at
│   │   │   └── migration.sql
│   │   ├── 20230202130457_mapping
│   │   │   └── migration.sql
│   │   └── migration_lock.toml
│   └── schema.prisma
```

can i choose one of these files to add my triggers inside or just create another file and add my triggers inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can declare database triggers that are a part of migrations.
You can create a migration with `--create-only` flag.

So invoking the command `npx prisma migrate dev --create-only` will create an empty migration file. You can then add the database trigger in this newly created file. Invoking `npx prisma migrate dev` again would then apply this new migration.

You can read more about customizing migrations [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/customizing-migrations).